# Convert UL navigation to dropdown navigation with select and putting active item on specific place

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Can you help me with converting unordered list navigation to dropdown navigation?

Currently I use this script

```
  $(function() {

    if (document.getElementById("level-2")) {
        initElement("#level-2");
    }
    if (document.getElementById("level-3")) {
        initElement("#level-3");
    }
    if (document.getElementById("embedded-level-3")) {
        initElement("#embedded-level-3");
    }


    function initElement(element) {
        $("<select />").appendTo(element);

        // Create default option "Go to..."
        $("<option />", {
            "selected": "selected",
            "value"   : "",
            "text"    : "Go to..."
        }).appendTo("nav"+element+" select");

        $(element + " a").each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            $("<option />", {
            "value" : el.attr("href"),

            "text"  : el.text()
        }).appendTo(element + " select");
    });

        $(element + " select").change(function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        });}
});
```

This scripts converts this list of "li" tags to select>option tags dropdowns

Active page is defined by `a.active(a class="active")`.

Is it possible to change script to put link from class "active" and text from link on first position on dropdown menu select>option instead of "Go to..."?

To be clear, what I'm looking for.

Need to find element with class 'active' from the list, put it on first position of select dropdown amd then put all other elements of list in select dropdwon

From this

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="link2" class="active">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

To this

```
<select>
<option class="active" value="link2>Link 2</option>
<option value="link1>Link 1</option>
<option value="link3>Link 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is question solved now? And one more thing: have you tried to do it by yourself? What is really your problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't solved(
I don't understand, how to get link with active class and put it to the first position on select. And most of all I don't understand how not to double this link in select then

Comment: Here is the [fiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/ct808fq2/).